# Adding a nav item via XML puts it in the UL but not the correct css classes. How can I add css in my xml?

Tags: magento2, xml, navigation

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="nav.sitehome"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link Name</argument> 
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link url</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block>
```

---

I successfully added a url to my top nav but no of the sequential css came with it. How can I add the correct classes so they end up inline with the other items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `attributes` argument to set `target="_blank"` to one of my custom links so you can add class with `attributes` argument in the same way

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="nav.sitehome">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link Name</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link url</argument>
        <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">your-custom-class</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```